# Is it possible to use pretrained UMAP model for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have the pretrained UMAP model and some dataset as part of common dataset, which is labeled.

I've trained the umap model and get the clusters of my cases using K-means. I also have some cases labeled well (not many of them, in comparing to the whole dataset size). I used semi-supervised I want to label the other cases using this model, since I see the model relates those case points to the defined class, how I can get the information, which case relates to some class?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.